# pd.DataFrame.drop Causing Additional Column to be Created

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

**CONTEXT**

I have a main dataset dataframe (`df` which I clean from an import. The code I am using to do this is:

```py
df = pd.read_excel("spots.xlsx")
```

The headers for this dataframe are as follows:

`Station    Day Date    Time    Daypart`

I have another dataframe (`df_chan` which I am using as my 'lookup' table which has the following headers:

`Station    Sales House`

I want to merge these two so as to replace the `Station` column in the main df with the `Sales House` column in the lookup df. I am aware that I need to merge these datasets and then remove the original `Station` column and move the `Sales House` column to the first index.

Now, when I merge the datasets using the below code, it merges fine.

```py
df = pd.merge(df, df_chan, on="Station", how="inner")
```

The above produces the following headers:

`Station    Day Date    Time    Daypart Sales House`

Which is as expected. However, when I apply the `df.drop()` method:

`df = df.drop(columns=['Station'])`

It is returning headers as below:

`Day    Date    Time    Daypart Sales House_x   Sales House_y`

So as you can see it is splitting the `Sales House` column.

**QUESTION**

Why is the `Sales House` getting split? And what is the fix?

I apologise if this is a bit difficult to understand - I have tried to explain the best I can!

**EDIT**

Adding in some rows from the dataframes for better context.

`df` before merge

```py
Out[35]:
    Station Day Date    Time    Daypart
3   CARLTON Mon 3AUG20  1213    DAYTIME
4   CARLTON Mon 3AUG20  2307    POSTPEAK
5   CARLTON Tue 4AUG20  1015    COFFEE
6   CARLTON Tue 4AUG20  1027    COFFEE
7   CARLTON Wed 5AUG20  1310    DAYTIME
```

`df_chan` before merge

```py
Out[36]:
    Station Sales House
0   4MUSIC  C4 OWN
1   4SEVEN  C4
2   5SELECT SKY
3   5STAR   SKY
4   5STAR+1 SKY
```

`df` after merge

```py
Out[37]:
    Station Day Date    Time    Daypart     Sales House
0   CARLTON Mon 3AUG20  1213    DAYTIME     CARLTON
1   CARLTON Mon 3AUG20  2307    POSTPEAK    CARLTON
2   CARLTON Tue 4AUG20  1015    COFFEE      CARLTON
3   CARLTON Tue 4AUG20  1027    COFFEE      CARLTON
4   CARLTON Wed 5AUG20  1310    DAYTIME     CARLTON
```

`df` after `.drop()` method

```py
Out[38]:
    Day Date    Time    Daypart   Sales House_x Sales House_y
0   Mon 3AUG20  1213    DAYTIME   CARLTON       CARLTON
1   Mon 3AUG20  2307    POSTPEAK  CARLTON       CARLTON
2   Tue 4AUG20  1015    COFFEE    CARLTON       CARLTON
3   Tue 4AUG20  1027    COFFEE    CARLTON       CARLTON
4   Wed 5AUG20  1310    DAYTIME   CARLTON       CARLTON
```

Comment: Which version of pandas are you working in?

Comment: @zhqiat Version: `0.25.1`

Comment: Can you please share a sample of both dataframes for better clarity?

Comment: @MayankPorwal I have added that for you

Comment: @Dean The sample you added has no matching records.

Comment: @MayankPorwal I have updated properly this time - sorry!

Comment: @MayankPorwal I have outputted using `df.head()` - there are matching records for all `Stations` and `Sales House`

Answer (score 0):

This may be a bug with pd. There are a couple of dataframe view vs copy bugs in the issue tracker which could be causing your problem. Items [30484](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/30484), [33438](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/33438) seem to somewhat accurately track the issue that you have seen.

As you create the dataframe in your sample code, `df` is recycled as the assignment variable repeatedly. Given the behavior, it appears that the merge is not properly dropping the duplicated `sales_house` column, likely due to how pandas handles drops with `inplace=True` or not.

If you want your code to 'just work', 2 options

1. Update to pandas > 1.0
2. Use new variable names for your assignment (`df2`, `df3`, etc vs just using `df`)

Answer (score -1):

Since you dropping only one column the following code should work. But I am not sure why column was split in that way.

```
df.drop('Station',axis=1)
```